# Java FX Как вивести в UI результат виполнения метода

Tags: java, javafx

Здраствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой, не могу вивести результат виполнения метода на десктопное окно так как `setText()` принимает только `String`, а метод `void`.

```
public static void createSession() throws Exception {

    session.getOnAuthenticationSuccessResponse().addObserver(authSuccessResponse ->{
            System.out.println("Auth success response received from authorization channel");

    });

    session.getOnAuthenticationFailedResponse().addObserver(authFailedResponse ->
            System.out.println("Auth failed response received from authorization channel - " + authFailedResponse.getFailedReason()));
  }
```

Ето сообщения которие я должен вивести на UI.

Ето мой контроллер

```
@FXML
private static TextArea Out;

public void Autentification(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {

    Connection.createSession();

    String name = "java_test002";// UserName.getText();
    String pass = "21918a";//Password.getText();
    String host = "m.islb.one";//Host.getText();

    String port = "30000";//Port.getText();
    int intPort = Integer.parseInt(port);


    Connection.session.tryConnect(name, pass, host, intPort);
 }
```

После нажатия кнопки юзер аутентифицируется и должны вивестись сообщения с метода выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вывести сообщение на Label, если он есть в вашем UI:

```
   public class TestLabel extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(args);
        }

        static Label outLbl ;

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {


            outLbl = new Label("Out msg");

            VBox root = new VBox(outLbl);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,300);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }

        public static void createSession() throws Exception {

            session.getOnAuthenticationSuccessResponse().addObserver(authSuccessResponse ->{
                // вместо  System.out.println используем элемент UI 
                outLbl.setText("Auth success response received from authorization channel");

            });

            session.getOnAuthenticationFailedResponse().addObserver(authFailedResponse ->
            // вместо  System.out.println используем элемент UI 
            outLbl.setText("Auth failed response received from authorization channel - " + authFailedResponse.getFailedReason()));
          }
    }
```

В этом случае outLbl это глобальная переменная.

Есть другой вариант , если добавить в Ваш метод параметр Label:

```
public static void createSession(Label outLbl) throws Exception {

                session.getOnAuthenticationSuccessResponse().addObserver(authSuccessResponse ->{
                    // вместо  System.out.println используем элемент UI 
                    outLbl.setText("Auth success response received from authorization channel");

                });

                session.getOnAuthenticationFailedResponse().addObserver(authFailedResponse ->
                // вместо  System.out.println используем элемент UI 
                outLbl.setText("Auth failed response received from authorization channel - " + authFailedResponse.getFailedReason()));
              }
        }
```